# finite normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

$G$ is a subgroup of finite index in $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, $n\ge 3$, $N$ is finite normal subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, then I want to know why $N$ is a normal subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$.

More generally, $A$ is an arithmetic subgroup of a simple algebraic $\mathbb{Q}$-group $G$ with $\mathbb{Q}$-$\operatorname{rank}(G)\ge 2$ and $N$ is a finite normal subgroup of $A$. Then $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. But I don't know why.

Comment: Surely, in your first question, the only finite subgroups that are normalized (and hence also centralized) by a finite index subgroup of ${\rm SL}(n,{\mathbb Z})$ are scalar subgroups.

Comment: Could you explain it more precisely? For example, what is scalar subgroups. Thank you.

Comment: I guess it should be finite index normal subgroup of $A$ otherwise as mentioned above, the question is trivial for $G = SL(n)$. One could invoke Borel Density to say that $A$ is zariski dense in $G$ and since $N$ is normal in $A$, it is zariski dense in $G$.